# Connection to SQL Server database blocked

Tags: node.js, sql-server

I have my app in Nodejs that is supposed to connect to SQL Server database.

```
const sql = require('mssql')

class DAO {
    constructor() {
        this.sqlConfig = {user: 'user', password: 'pwd', server: '192.168.102.232\\SQLEXPRESS', database: 'PROFACE'}
    }

    async connect() {
        try {
            console.log("Connecting database.....");
            let pool = await sql.connect(this.sqlConfig);

            if (pool)
                console.log("Database connected");
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    }   
}

module.exports = DAO;
```

```
const Server = require('./server/Server');
const DAO = require('./server/DAO');
const express = require('express');

const server = new Server();
const dao = new DAO();
server.start();
dao.connect();
```

But I don't know why, it doesn't work. The program stay blocked at `console.log("Connecting database.....");` in DAO.js connect().

Any idea?

Comment: Is any errors in console??

Comment: No, there is no error in console...

Comment: make sure you can access  the db

Comment: I tried to access db through SQL Server Manager and I can access it

Answer (score 1):

**

> First of all, change your password of the database immediately. You
>   have exposed this over the internet. You should never do this.

**

For your answer, you can use: connectionTimeout attribute of config to know whether you are able to reach the server or not.

Comment: Oh god that's true, I forgot to change ! Thank you !

Comment: For connectionTimeout, is it like this that I should use it :
````
this.sqlConfig = {
   user: 'connexionMartin', 
   password: 'InfoMartin', 
   server: '192.168.102.232\\SQLEXPRESS', 
   database: 'PROFACE',
   connectionTimeout = 30}
 }````

Comment: Yes, same way:
const config = {
    user: '...',
    password: '...',
    server: 'XYZ',
    database: '...',
    pool: {
        max: 10,
        min: 0,
        idleTimeoutMillis: 30000
    }
}
BTW, default timeout is 15 seconds.

Also, check your connection string: "192.168.102.232\\SQLEXPRESS"